How to reduce no. of realm-mongodb sync operations in expo-react-native app
App.tsx:
import AppWrapper from './src/AppWrapper';
import { SYNC_CONFIG } from './src/configs/sync.config';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { ThemeProvider } from './src/components/common/ThemeContext';

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppWrapper appId={SYNC_CONFIG.appId} />
    </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>

  );
}

AppWrapper.tsx:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { AppProvider, UserProvider, RealmProvider } from '@realm/react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Navigator from './components/common/Navigator';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import { schemas } from './models';
import { ProfileModel } from './models/ProfileModel';
import { Exercise, ExercisePose } from './models/Exercise';
import { WorkoutModel, BodyWeightWorkoutEntry, YogaWorkoutEntry,WeightModel, CardioModel } from './models/WorkoutModel';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Routine } from './models/Routines';
import YogaWorkoutModel from './models/Yoga';
import FlashMessage from "react-native-flash-message";

const AppWrapper: React.FC<{
  appId: string;
}> = ({ appId }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // Use useNavigation to get the navigation prop
  

  const realmAccessBehavior: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration = {
    type: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorType.OpenImmediately,
  };
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
     <SafeAreaView className="flex-1" style={{ backgroundColor: true ? theme.colors.secondary : theme.colors.secondary }}>
        <AppProvider id={appId}>
          <UserProvider fallback={<Login />}>
            <RealmProvider
              schema={schemas}
              path={"/data1.realm"}
              sync={{
                flexible: true,
                newRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
                existingRealmFileBehavior: realmAccessBehavior,
                initialSubscriptions: {
                  update(subscriptions, realm) {
                    const objectTypes = [
                      CardioModel,
                      WeightModel,
                      ProfileModel,
                      WorkoutModel,
                      YogaWorkoutModel,
                      YogaWorkoutEntry,
                      BodyWeightWorkoutEntry,
                      Routine,
                      Exercise,
                      ExercisePose
                    ];
                    objectTypes.forEach(objectType => {
                      subscriptions.add(realm.objects(objectType));
                    });
                  },
                },
              }}
            >
              <Navigator />
              <FlashMessage position="top" />
            </RealmProvider>
          </UserProvider>
        </AppProvider>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper;




I see the same log repeated over and over again.
Hi all,
I'm new to react-native and need help with sync issues in my expo react-native realm app.
As seen above, I have multiple sync requests running every sec for very short periods. I have these sync requests running even when there is no data change to sync in app.
I want to reduce the no. of sync requests made to the cloud to keep my app viable in the free tier of mongodb. I think it would be better to  sync data manually only through a sync button and stop the auto sync or have code to sync code only once a day. I aslo would like to understand why do i see so many sync calls every second?
Any suggestions?

The free tier includes 1,000,000 requests and is generally plenty for development purposes. It doesn't look like much data is being sync'd but it would be helpful to know what those sync->other transactions consist of - clicking the arrow on the right of any of them will reveal more information. Please do that and include further details in your question.

I have added the log detail of a sync transaction as requested, please take a look

That helps. It appears a new query is being issued based on what's in the screenshot. Keep in mind that Realm is an offline first database so queries will be run against local data and sync'd later. Looking at what is being sync'd, it involves Exercise and Yoga, but there's nothing in your code that references those objects. So it's possible other code is being run.

My code was a sample code where I had replaced the object models with sample ObjType1 and ObjType1 to keep it simple for stackoverflow. I have however updated the question with my actual code now.

The code in the question still doesn't correlate to what's being reported. That code sets up Realm and the models, keeping in mind that the sync includes Yoga (per the screen shot) but nothing in that code shows Yoga. So the issue appears to be unrelated to that code. I would guess there's a query elsewhere in the code that's being run - possibly in a loop or a view that's being refreshed repeatedly.
